# Bi Publisher date format not working in RTF template

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I am using xdoxslt:sysdate('DD-Mon-YY') at the bottom of report in footer section.
whenever report runs - it generates around 5-8 pages as per data and in every page at the footer i want see sysdate.
At 1st page date comes fine like 15-Sep-17 but at 2nd page it is coming incorrect 12/02/7. 
Did anyone faced this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a built in word/rtf function for the date that you could use.

*Ribbon -> Insert -> Date & Time*

There's also a function to have a different footer on first page. Make sure you don't have that checked.

*When in the footer, should show "Design" in the ribbon, and in the Options, there's a "Different First Page"*